# Simple beta hedging questions

Tags: beta, optimal-hedge-ratio

This might sound really naive but I am really confused by this beta hedging idea.

So it seems the standard way to do it is to run a simple OLS on returns (say asset A and B only 2 assets in the portfolio). And then you will have a formula rtn_a = beta * rtn_b + e, which means if B goes up by 1% tomorrow, A will go up by beta%. Now if I want to implement this hedge, I guess I should long 1 share of A and short beta shares of B, right? But if I apply the weights to the price at day 1 and see how the portfolio evolve over time (in-sample backtest sort of), I will get a very different results than I expected... Volatility of this portfolio is just all over the place. Am I doing it wrong? Or what's the correct way to convert this beta ratio to # of shares? Or one should really dynamically adjust this hedge ratio?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using for B ? Rather than a random stock one should use an index ETF that is highly correlated with A such as SPY, VTI etc. That is how "beta hedging" is generally understood. Even then it will not be a perfect hedge by any means.

Comment: @nbbo2 yeah let's just assume B is an index SPY, I guess I am just confused about the implementation. Should I just short beta shares of B and long 1 share of A? I guess how do you compute weights in this case. Is the weights w_A = 1 / (1+beta) and w_B = beta / (1+beta)? Thanks!

Comment: How big is your A position in dollars (price times shares)? Say 1000 USD. Then you need a position in B that is this number times beta, for ex 1000*beta. You know the price of B so you can find the needed shares of B so that they have this dollar value.

Comment: ...then when the value of B increases by x% and the value of A increases by beta*x%, these two P&L's will offset each other.